# Why does Python keep giving me the error 'ImportError: No module named c4d' when I run the code?

Tags: python, importerror

I am VERY new to Python. (I literally just installed it 5 Minutes ago). Let's just say that I am acquiring some software and it said that once I had placed the files where they need to be I need to run the .py file and it will generate a license.lic file. These are the exact insturctions "Run Renderking_C4Dome_2_KG.py and place the license.lic it generates in to the main C4Dome plugin directory."
The code in the Renderking_C4Dome_2_KG.py file is:

[Renderking_C4Dome_2_KG.py Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAZDQ.png)

The error I get is:

[Renderking_C4Dome_2_KG.py ImportError: No module named c4d](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0BN0.png)

If it helps the code was made using Python 2 and I am running it in Python 2.
I am sorry If I didn't explain it very well. I am very VERY new to Python.

Do any of you have any idea why this is happening or how to fix it?

Comment: Please edit your question to include both the code and error message in it, instead of linking to them.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the error is missing c4d.py file which has been imported in the code. Python searches the imported files in paths defined using the PATH and PYTHON_PATH environment variables.

Comment: I found a c4d.py file in the software im installing to. How would I change the path to this file location?

Comment: You can copy the c4d.py file in the same path you have your renderking_c4dome_2_KG.py file.